# Want to update multiple records using checkboxes and save button

Tags: php

I am searching some records using two text boxes and then updating the selected records in database. i am able to see the value row id of the selected checkbox but when i want to get the value for updation in database it gives 0, i.e showing no record in array

Here is my code

```
if($_POST["search"])
{
    $nitnumber = $_POST["nitnumber"];
    $workno = $_POST["workno"];
    $query = "select * from print where nit = $nitnumber and work = $work";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("<font color =red>NIT Number and/or Work Number is Missing</font>");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0)
    echo "<font color=red>Record not found</font>";
                else
                {
                while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                ?>  
  <tr class="odd">
  <td><div align="center"><?php echo $record['a']; ?></div></td>
  <td><div align="center"><?php echo $record['b']; ?></div></td>
  <td><div align="left"><?php echo $record['c']; ?></div></td>
  <td> <div align="left">
<?php 
   enter code hereecho $record["d"];    
           ?>                   
          </td>
            <td> 
                <input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $record[$id];?>">                        
                <?php echo $record["id"];?>
            </td>
            <?php } } }?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" align="right"> <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"> </td>
            </tr>

<?php    
 if ($_POST['save'])
{
       $num_chkboxes=count($_POST['checkbox']);
       for($i=0; $i<$num_chkboxes; $i++){
       $complete = intval($checkbox[$i]);
       echo $complete;
       var_dump($complete);
       echo $updateSQL = "UPDATE toDo SET complete=1, WHERE toDoId=$complete";
       //$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $FamilyOrganizer) or die(mysql_error());
}
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem started when you fill the values of the checkboxes:

```
<input name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $record[$id];?>" />
```

you must gave them the value like

```
value="<?php echo $record['id'] ?>"
```

Second, you don't get the values of the checkboxes as you should:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['checkbox']); $i++){
   $complete = intval($_POST['checkbox'][$i]);
   //echo $complete;
   //var_dump($complete);
   echo $updateSQL = "UPDATE toDo SET complete=1, WHERE toDoId=$complete";
}
```

Another thing you should take care about is the assigning of the elements ids:

```
id="checkbox[]"
```

you must give unique ids for each element:

```
id="checkbox-1"
id="checkbox-2"
```

Comment: i gave different ids and used the same code which you have mentioned but still the same result. Getting 0 in complete variable..

Comment: See my edited answer.. there are multiple problems in your script

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php    
     if ($_POST['save'])
    {

       $checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];
        $selected_checkbox = "";
        foreach ($checkbox1 as $checkbox1) 
        {
            $selected_checkbox .= $checkbox1 . ", ";
        }
        $selected_checkbox = substr($selected_checkbox, 0, -2);
       $updateSQL = "" // your update query here
    }
?>    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value=""> // take checkboxes like this
```

Comment: How you are getting unique value of each checkbox? as you left blank space for value in the input field? actually i am trying to pass the row id to the query of the selected items.

Comment: i have just given you an example you can take any value like.. <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="Casting">Casting

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="<?php echo $record["id"];?>">.... its takes the array of all checkboxes